# Display object inside object in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Here's my object inside EntryList variable in my component

```
{
    "id": 0, 
    "startAddress": {
       "id": 6,
       "addressString": "addressString"
    },
    "endAddress": {
       "id": 6,
       "addressString": "addressString"
    },
    "distanceInKm": 5.637376656633329,
    "travelTime": "travelTime",
    "standingTime": "standingTime",
    "vehicle": {
       "id": 2,
       "licensePlateNumber": "licensePlateNumber"
    },
    "driver": {
       "id": 7,
       "name": "name"
    }
}
```

I want to display columns: driverName, vehicleName, startAdrress, endAdress, distanceInKm, travelTime, standingTime.

I tried using `<tr *ngFor="let DLBlist of EntryList">` but there's no display.

Comment: NgFor is for arrays only, and your data is an object. You’ll need to restructure your data first

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: EntryList.startAddress.id

Answer (score 1):

Those are nested elements. You can access them with the following code

```
DLBlist?.driver?.name
DLBlist?.startAddress?.addressString
DLBlist?.endAddress?.addressString
```

`?.` is the safe access operator, so if they don't exist no error is thrown